# Google Script Class CalendarEvent

Tags: google-apps-script, google-calendar-api

I am pretty basic with coding, so sorry if that seems very obvious to you.
My request is how to get the name of the "guest" using the class CalendarEvent, getGuestList?
https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/calendar/calendar-event#getGuestList%28%29

Code test 1:

```
// Loop through all calendar events found and write them out starting on calulated ROW 2 (i+2)
for (var i=0;i<events.length;i++) 
{
var row=i+2;
// Matching the "header=" entry above, this is the detailed row entry "details=", and must match the number of entries of the GetRange entry below
var details=[[events[i].getTitle(),events[i].getStartTime(),events[i].getLocation(),events[i].getGuestList(),events[i].getDescription()]];
var range=sheet.getRange(row,1,1,5);
range.setValues(details);
}
```

Issue code 1: I have for "guestName" result: **EventGuest** (instead of the name or email address)

If I try this code, code test 2:

```
//Loop through all calendar events found and write them out starting on calulated ROW 2 (i+2)
for (var i=0;i<events.length;i++) 
{
var row=i+2;
//Matching the "header=" entry above, this is the detailed row entry "details=", and must match the number of entries of the GetRange entry below

// trying to get guest name
var Nameguest = events[i].getGuestList(); 

var details=[[events[i].getTitle(),events[i].getStartTime(),events[i].getLocation(),**Nameguest[i].getName()**,events[i].getDescription()]];
var range=sheet.getRange(row,1,1,5);
range.setValues(details);
}
```

Issue code 2: it is writing only the 1st line with the correct name displayed, but then the script stops and provide this error: ***"TypeError: Cannot call method "getName" of undefined. (line xx, file "") Dismiss "***

Hopefully it is an easy answer :)

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

`.getGuestList()` returns an array you have to loop through separately from the outer events loop.

`Nameguest[i]` is using the same `i` counter that only `events` should be using.

instead try:

```
var names = "";
var guestList = events[i].getGuestList();
for ( var n = 0; n < guestList.length; n++ ) {
  var name = guestList[n].getName(); 
  if ( name ) {
    names += name + ', ';
  }
}

var details=[[events[i].getTitle(), ..., names, ...]];
```

Comment: Hello Bryan,
Thank you very much for your swift feedback.
Unfortunately, it doesn't give any data in the cell.
I have copied your code and there is no error message, but nothing in the cell.
Any idea?
Thank you again.

Comment: the last line should not be copied over as-is. have a look at the debugging techniques in Apps Script

Comment: Hello Bryan, of course, I didn't copy the last line as it is.  But it doesn't seem to work as it is unfortunately. I am actually looking to get only 1 name... as there will be mostly one guest per event (plus the organizer, of course). Thanks